# Why does my regex for "include?" not work?

Tags: watir-webdriver, testunit

I'm using Watir WebDriver and test/unit with Firefox.

The following code works:

```
assert(@browser.text.include?("Company employees"))
```

Why does the following code not work?

```
assert(@browser.text.include?(/Company employees/))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [String#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method only accepts strings or characters. It does not accept regular expressions.

You can use either of the following to assert against the regexp:

```
assert(@browser.text.match(/Company employees/))
assert(@browser.text =~ /Company employees/)
assert(@browser.text[/Company employees/])
```

However, I think it is more clear (reading the code and the error message) if you use the assert_match:

```
assert_match(/Company employees/, @browser.text)
```

Comment: All three suggestions work. I agree that third suggestion is clearer. Forcing a failure is an easy way to print out all the text on the page :)

Comment: The recommendation is usually to check a specific element's text rather than the whole page. It reduces chances of false positives and saves your error message from printing the whole page.

Comment: Agreed. For laziness, I used `text` for 6 asserts on a page. When I changed each `text` to each of the 6 specific elements, the asserts took only a fraction of the original time.

Answer (score 0):

try assert(@browser.text.include?("/Company employees/"))

Comment: the / should be escaped by a preceding \ . This works for my include? tests with regular expressions